# how to find duplicate count without counting original

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I need to count the number of duplicate emails in a mysql database, but without counting the first one (considered the original). In this table, the query result should be the single value "3" (2 duplicate x@q.com plus 1 duplicate f@q.com).

TABLE

```
ID | Name  | Email
1  | Mike  | x@q.com
2  | Peter | p@q.com
3  | Mike  | x@q.com
4  | Mike  | x@q.com
5  | Frank | f@q.com
6  | Jim   | f@q.com
```

My current query produces not one number, but multiple rows, one per email address regardless of how many duplicates of this email are in the table:

```
SELECT value, count(lds1.leadid) FROM leads_form_element lds1 LEFT JOIN leads lds2 ON lds1.leadID = lds2.leadID 
     WHERE lds2.typesID = "31" AND lds1.formElementID = '97'  
     GROUP BY lds1.value HAVING ( COUNT(lds1.value) > 1 )
```

Comment: you can use `SUM` as `SUM(count(lds1.leadid))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not one query so I'm not sure if it would work in your case, but you could do one query to select the total number of rows, a second query to select distinct email addresses, and subtract the two. This would give you the total number of duplicates...

```
select count(*) from someTable;
select count(distinct Email) from someTable;
```

In fact, I don't know if this will work, but you could try doing it all in one query:

```
select (count(*)-(count(distinct Email))) from someTable
```

Like I said, untested, but let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a group by in a sub query and then summing up. Something like:

```
select sum(tot)
from
(
    select email, count(1)-1 as tot
    from table
    group by email
    having count(1) > 1
)
```